# "Achievements" toolbar at SE proposes that new users edit their profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, network-profile, achievements-dialog

Upon creating a new account, users are shown the below message if they click the "Achievements" toolbar next to the inbox on the top:

[image: "You have not yet earned any achievements. Why not take the tour or fill out your profile?"]

The first link works in any network site you may see the notification in, and redirects the user to the "tour" page that relates to that site (i.e., to stackexchange.com/tour if your on stackexchange.com, or to meta.stackexchange.com/tour if you're here on Meta SE, and so on).

The second link tries to behave in the same way, except the problem is if the user's on stackexchange.com, which has no profile editing capabilities, it redirects the user to [a "Page not found" page](https://stackexchange.com/users/edit/current).

---

Also, forgot to thank the new user who found and reported this!

Comment: Good find, I'm not sure where that could go though... Maybe their oldest account page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [image]

Problem solved*. =)

<sub>* as of next build</sub>